# pandas - time difference between last events of different groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of messages, their sender and time. It looks similar to this:

```
Time           Person    Message
8:00           A         '1'
8:01           B         '2'
8:02           B         '3'
8:05           A         '4'
9:04           B         '5'
```

I want to calculate how long it took a person to respond to the other person's last message. i.e get the following:

```
Time           Person    Message     TimeDiff(in min)
8:00           A         '1'         0
8:01           B         '2'         1
8:02           B         '3'         2
8:05           A         '4'         3
9:04           B         '5'         59
```

How can I reach this goal?

Edit:
Note this isn't a simple diff with the last element in the Time col as it's conditioned on the Person column. See example.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a datetime series to calculate the difference.

First get the serie using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
date_time_serie=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'] ,format = '%H:%M')
```

Then calculate the difference using [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [dt.second](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html):

```
df['TimeDiff(in min)']=date_time_serie.diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)).dt.seconds/60
df['TimeDiff(in min)']=df['TimeDiff(in min)'].astype(int)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Time Person Message  TimeDiff(in min)
0  8:00      A     '1'                 0
1  8:01      B     '2'                 1
2  8:02      B     '3'                 1
3  8:05      A     '4'                 3
4  9:04      B     '5'                59
```